# AMP isn't loading completely in mobile devices?

Tags: amp-html

Well I have built a website(aptadvantage.com) in AMP and it works perfectly when I use the direct URL whereas when I am trying to search the url in google searchbar and load the same from search results on mobile device its not loading the page completely and the link also changes.
I am attaching the image below.[image: Hers the image that shows the way it loads on mobile devices when trying to open the website from google search result]

Answer (score 1):

Only your articles are valid AMP documents, loading your homepage reveals over 115 validation errors, which means it will be ignored by the Google cache. Your article pages on the other hand validate just fine, and are shown to me when I search for your page's articles on Google.

**Validation Results**: https://validator.ampproject.org/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aptadvantage.com%2F